# Sprite Builder can't find the variable define in objective c class

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am making a game given in `makeagamewithus.com` named `"PeevedPenguins"`. 
I put _physicsNode variable in spritebuilder for gameplay scene and put `CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode` in implementation class Gameplay as given in this [Link](https://www.makegameswith.us/tutorials/getting-started-with-spritebuilder/creating-two-levels/).
 But get an error `CBReader: Couldn't find member variable: _physicsNode`

Comment: Yeah you should make sure to double check everything. This functionality is one of the core things in SP and is working properly. From what you are describing, one of the possible pitfalls you may have fallen into is forgetting to export your project. Is that it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am really new to this , can you please specify where to export my project ? TIA.

Comment: After you make changes you have to push the big publish button that is in the top left corner. Then you would go on to open the xcode project in your APPNAME.spritebuilder folder.

Comment: Yeah i am publishing the project event cleaning the cache before publishing but not working. Is there any problem regarding the storage of file in source folder or any other folder ? Because when i use **Owner var** it does not show 'Couldnt find member varaible: _physicsNode' but gets nill in _physicsNode. TIA

Comment: No, *owner var* is different. Use owner var when you want to present a pause menu for example. You would set the owner var to your PauseMenuController that you define to neatly seperate pause menu code from normal game code. Could you provide a zip with your project? I could take a look over it.

Comment: To get the project please click [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mgpxz2wdx077yze/PeevedPenguins.spritebuilder.zip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You we're not declaring your `ivars` correctly in your class.

Here is the problematic snippet from your code.

```
@implementation Gameplay
CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
CCNode *_catapultArm;
```

You forgot the brackets, here is your corrected code.

```
@implementation Gameplay
{
    CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
    CCNode *_catapultArm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In spritebuilder make sure the pop-up menu is set to "Doc root var".
Check your capitalization and spelling.
Make sure the superclass of Gameplay is CCNode.